# CSS/HTML5 equivilent to iframe marginheight and marginwidth

Tags: html, iframe, css, margin

I am doing a website layout for a company who uses IDevAdManager for rotating ads on their site.  Unfortunately, I am not much of an expert in that field, so I can't give much on that.  What I can say for sure though, due to the nature of the generator, the source inside the iframes it generates are not editable by me.

Now, here is my problem.

I am trying to make their new website HTML5 compliant, but I have reached an interesting issue.

When it comes to adding the iframes from the ad rotator, it generates all of the old, depreciated tags used by previous implementations of HTML.

Obviously, most of this is removable with CSS.  All except, however, for the marginheight and marginwidth attributes.

Here is where I reach my problem.  There does not seem to be a CSS equivalent to either marginheight or margin width, and there is no way to access the source within the iframes.  However, leaving them out prevents the inner content from lining up properly.

I am hoping to find a solution that is both valid HTML5, and solves my problem.

Does such an option currently exist?  Or will I have to use the deprecated tags until a solution is designed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is a valid question. Unfortunately it turns out that the marginheight, marginwidth and frameborder are properties of the iframe element itself, not the element's style property see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_marginheight.asp

So, for example, you can do this in JavaScript:-

```
document.getElementById("SomeIframe").marginheight = "0";
```

but you CANNOT do this

```
document.getElementById("SomeIframe").style.marginheight = "0";
```

and setting the margin has NO EFFECT (i.e. you will still get the default margin in the iframe element):-

```
document.getElementById("SomeIframe").style.margin = "0";
```

So the answer to cbright6062's question is that there is no way to set the marginheight, marginwidth and frameborder properties of an iframe in a style sheet.

Comment: When referencing w3schhols you should have read this:
--- The <iframe> marginwidth attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. ---

But what you're doing by JS is setting the attribute marginwidth afterwards to the iframe and so is not HTML5 valid as the authoer asked for...

Answer (score 1):

To be HTML5 valid the document inside the iframe has to get the correct style, not the iframe itself.
I don't know that adManager thing but it depends on how the iframe is created.

If it is dynamic and sameorigin you can enter it by

```
document.getElementById("SomeIframe").contentDocument;
```

and set margin by style to 0.

```
let myFrameBody = document.getElementById("SomeIframe").contentDocument.querySelector('body');
myFrameBody.style.margin = 0;
```

If it is not sameorigin the owner of the document has to set this by himself,
and that is never a bad idea, and also regarding HTML4.1 this would be considered valid.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late to the party, but using css to set the padding of the iframe ought to do the trick.