# Why does HTML5 doesn't validate but doesn't give an alternative either?

Tags: css, html, validation, iframe

I don't understand HTML 5. A validator says:

> The marginwidth attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
>   The marginheight attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

But according to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286888/css-html5-equivilent-to-iframe-marginheight-and-marginwidth):

> there is no way to set the marginheight, marginwidth and frameborder properties of an iframe in a style sheet.

Why do they ask me to do something that is just impossible?

Either put the thing that works in the specification or come up with a real alternative. They appear to have deprecated something and their alternative doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does CSS `margin` or `padding` work?

Comment: _“What am I missing here?”_ – that a description of the _actual_ problem you are facing could be much more helpful …

Comment: @CBroe the question is about practice. How can someone write valid HTML5 with iframes, when they want to customize the margins and borders of said iframe.

Comment: @TylerH: And I would like to know what specifically the OP can’t achieve by using CSS-properties margin, padding and border …

Comment: @CBroe you're assuming the question is "How can I achieve..." when so far it seems to still be simply "*Can* I achieve".

Comment: @TylerH: The _“what”_ part behind “can I achieve” is still missing – that’s why I asked for a specific problem description.

Comment: @CBroe I think it's pretty clearly implicit. If it bothers you that it's not obvious enough, you should edit the question to include it.

Comment: It's simple: marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" DOn't validate but there's no way to achieve this with css, margin:0, pading:0, etc doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 spec does describe [how the marginheight and marginwidth attributes work.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/rendering.html#the-page) What it says is:

> For each property in the table below, given a body element, the first
>   attribute that exists maps to the pixel length property on the body
>   element. If none of the attributes for a property are found, or if the
>   value of the attribute that was found cannot be parsed successfully,
>   then a default value of 8px is expected to be used for that property
>   instead.
>
> ```
> Property        Source
> 'margin-top'    body element's marginheight attribute
>                 The body element's container frame element's marginheight attribute
>                 body element's topmargin attribute
> 'margin-right'  body element's marginwidth attribute
>                 The body element's container frame element's marginwidth attribute
>                 body element's rightmargin attribute
> 'margin-bottom' body element's marginheight attribute
>                 The body element's container frame element's marginheight attribute
>                 body element's bottommargin attribute
> 'margin-left'   body element's marginwidth attribute
>                 The body element's container frame element's marginwidth attribute
>                 body element's leftmargin attribute
> ```
>
> If the body element's Document's browsing context is a nested browsing
>   context, and the browsing context container of that nested browsing
>   context is a frame or iframe element, then the container frame element
>   of the body element is that frame or iframe element. Otherwise, there
>   is no container frame element.

So to achieve the same effect, you must set the CSS margin values on the body element of the contained page, not the CSS margin values of the iframe element.

The spec then goes on to explain why marginwidth and marginheight may not (or even should not) be supported in browsers:

> **Warning!** The above requirements imply that a page can change the margins of another page (including one from another origin) using, for example, an iframe. This is potentially a security risk, as it might in some cases allow an attack to contrive a situation in which a page is rendered not as the author intended, possibly for the purposes of phishing or otherwise misleading the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to say you should always remain *a bit sceptical* of information on W3C.

If you want to boil it down to literals- they are correct- there is no **direct** equivalent in CSS, however, CSS does provide existing alternatives (which is why neither property is still supported, they are redundant).

`marginheight` is the top and bottom margin, so just use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`...the same is true for `marginwidth`, use `margin-left` and `margin-right` (or specify all together in `margin`)

As for `frameborder`- simply set the `border` of the iFrame in CSS.

`<iframe marginheight='10' marginwidth=20' frameborder='0'>`

Can be accomplished in HTML/CSS with:

`<iframe>`

```
iframe{
  margin:10px 20px;
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: When i do 
margin:0;
The iframe still have margins.
marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" Works, but doesn't validate.

Comment: You likely have either conflicting CSS, or a margin/padding on the surrounding content

Comment: Chrome shows no conflict margin=0; padding=0; simply does nothing to  iframe margins. border=none; works as intended but can't get rid of the margins. Only inlining marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" does what it's supposed to do. I think tatty final statement is just right on the question i linked in my OP.

Comment: Are you setting as CSS styles or attributes?

Comment: Hmm i just give the iframe a class and style that class on my css.